# Items in Root.plist are not display in settings. iOS9/Xcode7-beta5

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7-beta5

None of my settings options are appearing for my project in iOS9. This happens not only with my project that has been converted to swift 2.0 but also the app from TestFlight which is Swift 1.2 compiled from Xcode 6. Is this an iOS 9 issue?

My problem is similar to [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9853) one. However, my setting never appear, even on the first launch.

Any ideas? Has anyone else come across this problem? Any input is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9853) in the apple dev forums.

"My settings were blank, too, even though they were fine in the simulator.  I ended up having to reset ALL settings and performing a full restore.  This was a PITA, since it required re-entering passwords and my thumbprints. I sure don't want my users to have to go through this after the ios9 GM release"

Comment: Thanks for the link, just restarting my device was sufficient for me. It may also be possible (untested) to just force-quit settings (swipe up) and restart the settings app.